# Heroku time out on deploy because of asset precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Problem: my Rails app won't deploy on Heroku (`Timed out compiling Ruby app (15 minutes)`)  because of assets precompilation.

I use gems (asset_sync, sprockets-image_compressor, image_optim) that cause slow asset precompilation. I also sync my assets to store them on S3. I had not have this issue before adding sprockets-image_compressor and image_optim gems

I could precompile assets locally but I would have to deal with my multiple environments (I have a staging app and a production app and I store my assets on different bucket on S3 regarding the environment) and I don't want to do that. And anyway that should be handled on deployment on Heroku.

I've also opened a ticket on Heroku asking them to increase the time out but I doubt they'll do that.

Any idea, suggestions?

Comment: Is this your first deploy to heroku, I mean with this app.  You could try  heroku run rake assets:clean, then try again to deploy.

Comment: It's not the first deploy but I did clean the repo with the heroku-repo. I'll try to clean the assets and I'll tell you of it worked but I doubt :/

Comment: I tried to clean the assets but it didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same issue, and also using image_optim gem. Basically the image precompilation process takes too long. So I modified Gemfile.
Changed:

```
gem 'image_optim'
```

To:

```
gem 'image_optim', :group => [:development]
```

Now I can precompile remotely on Heroku :D. Oh, this solution works pretty good for me since I compress all images manually using `image_optim -r *` in the folder where images are. And then push all image optimizations to my repository.
Cheers!